# Vuejs hide component on signup page with v-if using quasar framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar

I am using quasar drawer and i want to hide the drawer on signup view, with my current code it does hide but the problems is that when i reload the signup page it still renders in the DOM in a few milliseconds and then drawer disappear.

I don't know how to fix it not seeing the drawer render in the DOM at all, or maybe have control on the drawer, set it to false by default and explicitly render it manually on other routes.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-header elevated class="bg-indigo-4">
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-toolbar-title class="flex flex-center"></q-toolbar-title>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

    <q-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      v-if="!$route.meta.hideDrawer"
      :width="300"
      :breakpoint="400"
    >
      <q-scroll-area
        style="height: calc(100% - 150px); margin-top: 150px; border-right: 1px solid #ddd"
      >
        <drawer-navigation></drawer-navigation>
      </q-scroll-area>
      <drawer-header></drawer-header>
    </q-drawer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DrawerNavigation from "@/components/navigation/DrawerNavigation";
import DrawerHeader from "@/components/navigation/DrawerHeader";
export default {
  components: {
    DrawerNavigation,
    DrawerHeader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: true
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

router/index.js

```
{
 path: "/employers/signup",
 name: "EmployersSignup",
 component: () =>
   import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/EmployerSignup.vue"),
 meta: { hideDrawer: true }
},
```

Comment: @sedska did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make another variable like `isDrawerHidden: false` and place in the `v-if` of the `q-drawer`

and use a watcher for the `!$route.meta.hideDrawer` and assing to the variable `isDrawerHidden` the value of the watched element